# Is there a line class which allows me to return any point on the line?

Tags: java, line, collision-detection

I am creating a top-view game engine for my own use, and I need to detect what the player would be able to see, and only render the objects the user can see. This is to reduce the amount of information the player can get in certain situations. Currently, I have a grid system with two different kinds of objects, objects that the player cannot see or walk through, and the floor. I want to be able to draw a line from the player to a grid point I want to see if it needs to be rendered, and if the line collides with any walls on the way there, not render the grid. Otherwise render it. Is there a line class that I can return any point on it to check to see if it collides with any walls on the way in Java?

Comment: Looking for ray-plane intersection? Not that hard to implement.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog I do not know how well that would work in a 2d plane.

Comment: The 2D version is just a ray-line intersection. Still not difficult to implement, with the added bonus that you don't need to store the normal.

Comment: @meowgoesthedog Okay, I'll look into it.